# How can I apply multiple lines to the conditioned choices of a drop-down menu-Google-Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I found a guide that allows me to condition a drop-down menu, depending on the choice made by another. The method I found, allows me to make this choice only for a couple of cells. How can I extend to more pairs of lines?
The steps I have taken are the following:

```
=Match(Pers!F3;C1:C;0)
=TRANSPOSE(INDIRECT("D" & B5 & ":K" & B5))
```

My list is composed:
[image]

With the formulas written before, I can get a cell conditioned by its previous one. If I select the Zone, I will present myself in the drop-down menu, only those in the area. Example if I choose Zone 1, I can choose New York, West Virginia, Virginia.

[image]

If I try to drag, I will always be able to select the states of the first Zone.

[image]

How can I do multiple lines?
Thank you!

Comment: After you drag, what formula is populated into the new cells (the ones you dragged to)?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using script, try this. The dropdowns are on Sheet1 and Zone and city data on Sheet2.

```
function onEdit(e) { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var s=ss.getActiveSheet()
  var sheet=e.source.getSheetName()
  var target=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2")
  var col=e.range.getColumn()
  var ro=e.range.getRow()
  if(col==1){
    var val=e.range.getValue()
  if(sheet=="Sheet1" && val=="Zone1"){
    s.getRange(ro,2,1,1).clearContent()//clear cell to update
    var cell = s.getRange(ro,2,1,1)//get cell to update
    var z1=target.getRange(2,2,1,3)//get cities for Zone1
    var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(z1)//define the rule
    cell.setDataValidation(rule)//set the data validation rule
   }
      else{//for Zone2
    s.getRange(ro,2,1,1).clearContent()      
    var cell = s.getRange(ro,2,1,1);
    var z2=target.getRange(3,2,1,3)
    var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(z2)
    cell.setDataValidation(rule);
      }}}
```

Here is my test sheet you can copy and try. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z9Pw8rvFvJNhItqOUaMkmUt8lohwTJKA22GVgPAIfWU/edit?usp=sharing